# filter:grayscale(100%) in IE 11 for images

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I have searched all over the internet but I didn't get any solution.

Can anyone say what is the alternative for the css3 `filter` and for `transistion3d` in IE 11 and IE 12?

I don't want to use any Plugins.

**Not for SVG 
i want for `<img>` tag**

Answer (score 1):

Since filter is not supported with IE11 - there is ie hacks like [this](https://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-ie11/) However it would have to include a lot of JS seen [here](https://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/) which would mean writing browser detection in JS and more. -

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add two kinds of images, one is the original image and another is a grayscale image. Then, using div to display these images. like this:

```
<style>
    .grayscale {
        background-image: url('images/Image1.jpg');
        background-size: cover; /* <------ */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }

        .grayscale:hover {
            background-image: url('images/imag1_gray.PNG') ;
            background-size: cover; /* <------ */
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
        }
</style>
<div class="grayscale" style="width:500px; height:500px">
</div>
```

the result like this:

[image]

In my option, I prefer to use some JQuery plugin, like [this](https://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-ie11/).